# Calling a data from a csv file and show into a html page using django

Tags: python, html, django

I am working on a project where I need to import data from a csv file and show an element (suppose the first element, that is first row first column). I am importing the data via a form.py file. There the code is:

```
import pandas as pd

from django.shortcuts import render

def allblogs(request):
    input_file = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header= None)

     return render(request, 'blog/allblogs.html',  {'name': input_file[0][0], 'age': input_file[0][1], 'job':input_file[0][2]})
```

The html page can be just:

```
{{name}}
```

But I am seeing nothing (no error as well) in the html output.
Can anyone help?

Comment: what happens when you print the input_file content?

Comment: well i tried just to print the contents of the input_file using the code mentioned in jupyter. it worked fine. But, when I use the code and the  part of html in django, I get a blank white page

Answer (score 0):

This will convert your dataframe into dict.

```
 dict1 = input_file.to_dict()
 return render(request, 'blog/allblogs.html', dict1)
```